# ajax and php to enter multiple forms input to database

Tags: php, ajax

I have a php generated form with multiple input fields the number of which is determined by user select. I would like to use an ajax function to enter all the data to database. The problem is that I am new to ajax and not sure ho to go about it. The ajax javascript function below is a sample of what I would like to achieve and I know it is not correct. Can someone point me in the right direction. I have looked around and from what I see, Json may be a solution but I know nothing about it and reading up on it I still don't get it.

sample ajax:

```
function MyFunction(){

var i = 1;
var x = $('#num_to_enter').val();
   while (i <= x){
    var name = $('#fname[i]').val();
    var lname = $('#lname[i]').val();
    var email = $('#Email[i]').val();
    i++;
 }
    $('#SuccessDiv').html('Entering Info.<img src="images/processing.gif" />');
     $.ajax({url : 'process.php',
    type:"POST",
   while (i <= x){
    data: "fname[i]=" + name[i] + "&lname[i]=" + lname[i] + "&email[i]=" + email[i],
    i++;
 }
     success : function(data){
    window.setTimeout(function()
    {
    $('#SuccessDiv').html('Info Added!');
    $('#data').css("display","block");
    $('#data').html(data);
    }, 2000);
        }
});
        return false;
          }
```

A sample of form :

```
<?php

   echo "<form method='post'>";

   $i=1;

    while($i <= $num_to_enter){

    $form_output .= "First Name:

    <input id='fname' type='text' name='fname[$i]'><br />

     Last Name:

    <input id='lname' type='text' name='lname[$i]'><br />

    Email:

    <input id='Email' type='text' name='Email[$i]'><br />

    $i++;

   }

   echo"<input type='button' value='SUBMIT' onClick='MyFunction()'></form>";

   ?>

Then DB MySQL Sample


   <?php
       while ($i <= $x){

    $x = $_POST['num_to_enter'];
    $fname = $_POST['fname[$i]'];
    $fname = $_POST['fname[$i]'];
    $fname = $_POST['email[$i]'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `mytable` 
    (`firstname`, `lastname`, `email`) VALUES ('$fname[$i]', '$lname[$i]', '$email[$i]');";

    $i++;

    }

   ?>
```

Comment: Check out this jquery plugin ... http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

Comment: Christopher Morrissey   not what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple demo of AJAX:

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" action="process.php" id="my_form">
    <input type="text" name="firstname[]">
    <input type="text" name="firstname[]">
    <input type="text" name="firstname[]">
    <input type="text" name="firstname[custom1]">
    <input type="text" name="firstname[custom2]">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
// listen for user to SUBMIT the form
$(document).on('submit', '#my_form', function(e){

    // do not allow native browser submit process to proceed
    e.preventDefault();

    // AJAX yay!
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action') // <- find process.php from action attribute
        ,async: true // <- don't hold things up
        ,cache: false // <- don't let cache issues haunt you
        ,type: $(this).attr('method') // <- find POST from method attribute
        ,data: $(this).serialize() // <- create the object to be POSTed to process.php
        ,dataType: 'json' // <- we expect JSON from the PHP file
        ,success: function(data){

            // Server responded with a 200 code

            // data is a JSON object so treat it as such
            // un-comment below for debuggin goodness
            // console.log(data);

            if(data.success == 'yes'){
                alert('yay!');
            }
            else{
                alert('insert failed!');
            }
        }
        ,error: function(){
            // There was an error such as the server returning a 404 or 500
            // or maybe the URL is not reachable
        }
        ,complete: function(){
            // Always perform this action after success() and error()
            // have been called
        }
    });
});
```

**PHP process.php**

```
<?php
/**************************************************/
/* Uncommenting in here will break the AJAX call */
/* Don't use AJAX and just submit the form normally to see this in action */

// see all your POST data
// echo '<pre>'.print_r($_POST, true).'</pre>';

// see the first names only
// echo $_POST['firstname'][0];
// echo $_POST['firstname'][1];
// echo $_POST['firstname'][2];
// echo $_POST['firstname']['custom1'];
// echo $_POST['firstname']['custom2'];

/**************************************************/

// some logic for sql insert, you can do this part

if($sql_logic == 'success'){

    // give JSON back to AJAX call
    echo json_encode(array('success'=>'yes'));
}
else{

    // give JSON back to AJAX call
    echo json_encode(array('success'=>'no'));
}
?>
```

Comment: MonkeyZeus Thanks for the response! I think you missed the part where there will be more then 1 fname field and so on hence fname[I]. Am I wrong??

Comment: AJAX will have no issue posting the input fields you need. It is up to you to handle them properly once PHP gets the data. Please see the edit

Comment: MonkeyZeus Can we go to chat and I will show you more of what I am working with??

Comment: Depends on what time zone you are in, I am in New York. I am also on my phone right now and won't be at a computer until tomorrow sometime

Comment: I am in NY also I'll try to catch you 2moro

Comment: MonkeyZeus are you there?

Comment: A boolean for success/fail would be better here

Comment: @scrowler I totally agree, I decided to use a verbose example based on my judgement of skill level

Comment: Fair enough, keep in mind that doing that encourages Chinese whispers in programming style and can become ingrained (look at using `$i` for iterators, `$row` for looping SQL results etc). I +1'd your answer anyway.

Comment: @scrowler Haha I appreciate the +1 and yes I am very aware of Chinese whisperers

Answer (score 0):

```
var postdata={};
postdata['num']=x;
   while (i <= x){
    postdata['fname'+i]= name[i];
    postdata['lname'+i]= lname[i];
    postdata['email'+i]= email[i];

    i++;
}
 $.ajax({url : 'process.php',
    type:"POST",
    data:postdata,
    success : function(data){
    window.setTimeout(function()
    {
    $('#SuccessDiv').html('Info Added!');
    $('#data').css("display","block");
    $('#data').html(data);
    }, 2000);
        }
});
```

PHP

```
$num=$_POST['num'];
for($i=1;i<=$num;i++)
{
 echo $_POST['fname'.$i];
 echo $_POST['lname'.$i];
 echo $_POST['email'.$i];
}
```

Comment: Patato, give me some time to work with this. Thanks for the response, will get back to you.

Comment: Patato  I think you are on the right track, I used your code with a few changes because I have more fields then shown here. Put the code through jsLint and it is saying too many errors to continue after 30%. Also, with the code in the file none of the other javascript will work. Can we go to chat and I'll show you what I have??

Comment: @CornHoleLI sorry for late, cause Im in china that's almost midnight

Comment: Palato are you there?

Comment: sorry, you can Email me zzh2@shu.edu.cn