# JSON input size limit in jQuery Ajax request

Tags: json, size, jquery-ajaxq

I am writing a jQuery ajax request to add some data to database (asp.net application). And the input of that request is data which has to be added into database. The output is a message which will tell whether the data is successfully inserted or not.

The issue is sometimes it will insert the data and sometimes it is going to ajax request error block. So I need to know the following things.

1) Is there any limit for the size of input data (which is in json format).(maximum 10 records with 8 fields.)
2) It is because of issue like long time waiting for response (it is taking some time to insert these data into DB as lot if calculations are there before the insertion. Anyway it’s not more than 10 sec).

Comment: As long as you use POST method size will not be an issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20249587/is-it-any-limit-for-post-data-size-in-ajax  ---  > This could be a reason..rt?

Comment: Yes, that could be the issue, if yours data is that long.