# How to post long string via AJAX jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to send long string with `$form.serialize()`data as follows.

```
var $form = $( this ),
url = $form.attr( "action" );
$.ajax({
    url: APP_URL+'/packs/add',
    type: 'POST',
    data: $form.serialize() + '&url=' + JSON.stringify(downloadURL),
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function(data){

});
```

The `downloadURL` is long string and it post half of them and lost the other part. How to post full string?

Comment: create a hidden field in your form and give it the desired value. It will be submitted as part of the form data

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20249587/is-it-any-limit-for-post-data-size-in-ajax

Comment: How long? Web servers usually have limits for the length of incoming calls

Comment: What Is `downloadURL`? I would think it's a string but then you stringify it so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `downloadURL` is a string you would have to encode the string with `encodeURIComponent`

```
$.ajax({
    url: APP_URL+'/packs/add',
    type: 'POST',
    data: $form.serialize() + '&url=' + encodeURIComponent(downloadURL),
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function(data){

});
```

Comment: Yes this is what I want. Thanks