# Angular ng-file-upload: Why is my form data is truncated?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload, multipartform-data, ng-file-upload

I have a form that needs to POST input data along with files. I am currently using `danialfarid/ng-file-upload` to handle the uploads. I'm passing in all the form data and files using the `data` parameter, so something like:

```
Upload.upload({
   url: 'submit',
   data: { formData: formData }
});
```

However, the data that the backend receives is cut off. I'm sending in an array of 10 objects (for example) and it looks like it cuts off in the middle of the 8th element. If I reduce the number of objects sent, it works fine, presumably because the data is not truncated.

I'm not exactly sure what I should be looking for or what would cause the data to cutoff. What could be the reason for this and how should I be sending the data so that everything is received on the backend?

Comment: Certain backend frameworks such as ASP.NET MVC have maximum content length for POST actions. Check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20249587/is-it-any-limit-for-post-data-size-in-ajax). You may need to specify a higher maximum depending on the framework you are using backend.

Comment: take a look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request