# Is there a limit for javascript array attributes?

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a 'var' array with 21 attributes and it works fine. But one additional attribute is added to my array the method stops working. Array data passed into the MVC controller. Is it impossible to use more than 21 attributes in a var array?

This is my ajax code used to send data into controller.

```
    var DailyStock = [];

    for (var i = 0; i <= 45; i++) {

        DailyStock.push(
            {
                "DatePeriod": CreateDate($("#currDate" + i + "").text()),
                "JctLMS": $("#jctLMS" + i + "").val(),
                "ConfLMS": $("#confLMS" + i + "").val(),
                "FutLMS": $("#futLMS" + i + "").val(),
                "ParclLMS": $("#parcelLMS" + i + "").val(),
                "JctLIOC": $("#jctLIOC" + i + "").val(),
                "ConfLIOC": $("#confLIOC" + i + "").val(),
                "FutLIOC": $("#futLIOC" + i + "").val(),
                "ParclLIOC": $("#parcelLIOC" + i + "").val(),
                "JctIOE": $("#jctIOE" + i + "").val(),
                "ConfIOE": $("#confIOE" + i + "").val(),
                "FutIOE": $("#futIOE" + i + "").val(),
                "ParclIOE": $("#parcelIOE" + i + "").val(),
                "JctLMSL": $("#jctLMSL" + i + "").val(),
                "ConfLMSL": $("#confLMSL" + i + "").val(),
                "FutLMSL": $("#futLMSL" + i + "").val(),
                "ParclLMSL": $("#parcelLMSL" + i + "").val(),
                "BargeLMS": $("#bargeLMS" + i + "").val(),
                "StockIHLMS": $("#stckinhandLMS" + i + "").val(),
                "BargeLIOC": $("#bargeLIOC" + i + "").val(),
                "StockIHLIOC": $("#stckinhandLIOC" + i + "").val(),
                "BargeIOE": $("#bargeIOE" + i + "").val()

            },
        );
    }

    DailyStock = JSON.stringify({ 'DailyStock': DailyStock });


    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../Home/SetQuantity',
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        data: DailyStock,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.Success == true) {
                alert('success');
            }
            else {
                alert('Error');
            }

        },          
    });
```

C# controller Json Result Method

```
    public JsonResult SetQuantity(List<DailyStock> DailyStock)
    {
        try
        { 
            DBHandle DB = new DBHandle();
           // DB.SetTable(DailyStock);
            return Json(new { Success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return Json(new { Success = false, ErrorMessage = ex.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Class

```
 public class DailyStock
{
    public DateTime DatePeriod { get; set; }
    public string JctLMS { get; set; }
    public string ConfLMS { get; set; }
    public string FutLMS { get; set; }
    public string ParclLMS { get; set; }
    public string JctLIOC { get; set; }
    public string ConfLIOC { get; set; }
    public string FutLIOC { get; set; }
    public string ParclLIOC { get; set; }
    public string JctIOE { get; set; }
    public string ConfIOE { get; set; }
    public string FutIOE { get; set; }
    public string ParclIOE { get; set; }
    public string JctLMSL { get; set; }
    public string ConfLMSL { get; set; }
    public string FutLMSL { get; set; }
    public string ParclLMSL { get; set; }
    public string BargeLMS { get; set; }
    public string StockIHLMS { get; set; }
    public string BargeLIOC { get; set; }
    public string StockIHLIOC { get; set; }

    public string BargeIOE { get; set; }


}
```

Comment: The answer is NO, js arrays/objects has no such a limitation. Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: what is that additional attribute & how you are adding that

Comment: *"I have a 'var' array with 21 attributes"* No you don't. You have an array with 46 entries. Each entry in the array is an *object* with 21 *properties*.

Comment: Technically it's an array with 46 objects with 21 properties each.

Comment: @UncleDave: LOL, I just realized I'd missed the loop and edited. :-)

Comment: You need to include your class definition for `DailyStock`

Comment: `DailyStock` is just the var name, the casing makes the syntax highlighter assume it's a type.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder > "BargeIOE" is the 22 attribute (property)

Comment: @DinukshiJayarathne: My bad, one array containing 46 objects with 22 properties. (All of which is then wrapped in an object with one property referring to that array, then stringified.)

Comment: @Hackerman My DailyStock class contains all 22 properties

Comment: Do you have any console errors? Please define "stops working".

Comment: You are actually pushing just one item (your object literal, which actually has 22 properties, not 21) into your array.

Comment: @UncleDave > It just doesn't hit the controller method. But it i remove  ' "BargeIOE": $("#bargeIOE" + i + "").val()' it hits.

Comment: I need to see the C# code for the `DailyStock` class....

Comment: Oh yeah THAT `DailyStock` class, completely missed that one, in which case I agree with @Hackerman, please show us your C# `DailyStock`

Comment: Because for what I see, when you add another property in your javascript object, but you do not add that in your C# class, then you are having some sort of mismatch, and that is why it doesn't works

Comment: @UncleDave Question upadated with the class

Comment: `DailyStock` looks fine - this does sound like a model binding error though, have you tried the classic "restart visual studio"? You'd be surprised how often it works.

Comment: @UncleDave I did. Still no luck,

Comment: May we see the HTML for `BargeIOE`?

Comment: @UncleDave I have checked the HTML, its the same html use for the other attributes. and the converted Jason also contains the value for BargeIOE without any issues.

Comment: The only suggestion I have left based on what you've shown is that the data type for BargeIOE isn't string, but if you've checked then it can't be that.

Comment: @UncleDave No i checked its a string value, and i did another thing. I removed the "StockIHLIOC": $("#stckinhandLIOC" + i + "").val() and kept  "BargeIOE": $("#bargeIOE" + i + "").val(), so 21 attributes, It hits now.

Comment: There is no such limitation on client side, but perhaps on your server side. Take a look at this post -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/20251602/3877877

Comment: @MartinE Thank you so much, that solved the issue. Please put it as answer, so i can mark it as the answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such limitation on client side, but perhaps on your server side. Take a look at this post -> [stackoverflow.com/a/20251602/3877877](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20251602/3877877)