# How to send more than 5 binary data with other details by Jquery to MVC controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, multipartform-data

> Unable to send more than five binary file to controller.

```
Getting Files by Id
var one= $("#one").get(0).files;
var two= $('#two').get(0).files;
var three= $('#three').get(0).files;
var four= $('#four').get(0).files;
var five= $('#five').get(0).files;
var six= $('#six').get(0).files;

//Appending in Form Data
var ObjEntity = new FormData();
ObjEntity.append("Id", 1);

//Registration
ObjEntity.append("Title", $('#Title').val());
ObjEntity.append("City", $('#City').val());

//Regulatory Documents
ObjEntity.append("one", one[0]);
ObjEntity.append("two", two[0]);
ObjEntity.append("three", three[0]);
ObjEntity.append("four", four[0]);
ObjEntity.append("five", five[0]);
ObjEntity.append("six", six[0]);


Calling Ajax
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: urlPath,
    data: ObjEntity,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (response) {
        alertify.alert('success');
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        alertify.alert('error');
    }
});
```

I am unable to send all six at a time but if I pass any of five it is being sent to controller. Kindly help.

Comment: Does [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20249587/is-it-any-limit-for-post-data-size-in-ajax) answer your question?

Comment: No. Still getting the same issue.

Comment: Do you have `Global.asax` file in your proect? you can catch the content size in the method `Application_BeginRequest` and let it path if overload.

Comment: increased the content size from web config. Solved