# jquery $.ajax() $.get() formatting?

Tags: jquery, ajax, url, get

Why does

```
$.get("/some-url", function(response-data){ #do something with response-data });
```

work in my project

but

```
$.get({
    url: "/some-url",
    success: function() {
        #do something with response data
    },
});
```

give me a bad request error...?

As far as I can tell, when I use `url:` the string is being converted into an object or something.  The request is sent to localhost:3000/object%20Object, while when I use the first way it gets routed correctly.

What am I missing?!  This is blowing my mind.  Thanks!

Comment: because `$.get` doesn't support that syntax. did you mean `$.ajax` for the second sample?

Comment: `$.get()` isn't defined to expect an `Object` -- [***`url`** Type: String*](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/). Only [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) supports that with [***`settings`** Type: PlainObject*](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings).

Comment: You're not the only one, I was just about to ask the same question when I found this :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing settings paramters like [`$.ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings), remove `{}` from get({})

[From jQuery Documentaion](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

`jQuery.get( url [, data ] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) ] [, dataType ] )`

```
$.get(
     "/some-url",{},
    function(resultData) {
        // do something with response data
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `$.get({` to `$.ajax({`

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/some-url",
    success: function(data) {
        #do something with response data
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Forget `$.get()` and `$.post()` altogether, they are merely wrappers for `$.ajax()` and simply set `type:'GET'` or `type:'POST'` for you, so learning `$.ajax()` is by far the most useful.

Check out my answer here

[ajax and php to enter multiple forms input to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20150130/ajax-and-php-to-enter-multiple-forms-input-to-database/20150474#20150474)