# $.ajax POST Undefined index

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, undefined

Apologies in advance for any mistakes. This is my first post on StackOverflow.

So basically I have a php function. Inside it is a jQuery click function with a variable, into which I'm saving the clicked element's text. I'm trying to send that variable's value to my Uredi.php file, via $.ajax function, to save it into a php variable. However, I'm getting an "Undefined index" error. Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Here's the code:

PHP function:

```
public function uredi()
{
?>
<script>
$('.edit').click(function(){

$('.naslov_edit').val($(this).text());
$('#on_top').hide();
var refId = $(this).text();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'uredi.php', 
        type: "POST",
        data: {id: refId},
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    }); 

});
</script>
<?php
}
```

Uredi.php:

```
<?php
include 'Funkcije.php';

$uredi = new urejanje();
$uredi->uredi();

$id = $_POST['id'];
echo $id;
?>
```

Funkcije.php is the file with the uredi() function.

EDIT: Thank you everyone for helping. I figured out the problem. Turns out I just had to clean up my code a bit.

Comment: since you are getting alert in success, problem should be with server side.

Comment: What does the full error say?

Comment: Alert is returning the HTML code of Uredi.php. Also, full error is Undefined index: id in ... on line 36.

Comment: The undefined index is on line 36 of the PHP code being returned, in other words $_POST['id'] is undefined.

Comment: Your file structure seems to be very strange. Could you properly label the filenames for your functions and HTML? Also, please see this answer for an ideal AJAX setup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20150130/ajax-and-php-to-enter-multiple-forms-input-to-database/20150474#20150474

Answer (score 0):

Why are you assigning $(this).text() to var id and then not using it in the $.ajax()? Remember scope and what doe $(this) actually reference within the $ajax()? I would also shy away from naming variables "id" Try:

```
var refId = $(this).text();
$.ajax({
    url: 'uredi.php', 
    type: "POST",
    //dataType: 'json',
    data: {id: refId},
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Oops. Thank you, I forgot to change that bit. I renamed my variable and used it in the $.ajax. It's still returning Undefined index error though.

Comment: If it's a PHP error, do a 
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_POST);
    echo '</pre>';

Comment: What is that supposed to return?

Comment: If you're getting an undefined index error, you need to see if "id" is actually coming through to the $_POST array. That way, you eliminate any javascript ajax problems and that the data is being passed correctly first. Then, you can narrow down where the error is coming from.

Comment: It returned an undefined index error, so I suppose it's javascript/ajax that are causing the problem

Comment: Did you try print_r($_POST) and not print_r($_POST['id'])? If you did just the post it would come back with undefined error not index error if you weren't posting. What I want you to look at is everyting that the POST array has in it - may be that the structure of the data is not correct - may be $_POST[0]['id'] or something.

Answer (score 0):

Use this;

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'uredi.php', 
    type: "POST",
    data: "id=" + refId,
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you please put your ajax response on your question as edit?

Comment: The alert inside the ajax function returns the whole HTML of uredi.php. Is that what you meant?

Comment: But, you have specified datatype json in your ajax, and you are returning html in your php side. Do not use html code in your php file. Probably, there is error message also belong to html code in alert message

Comment: Sorry, that should be inside a comment. I'll remove it

Comment: I suggest you to remove all check your code above $_POST["id"], they are causing problem

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you meant to read the post vars before initializing the class and maybe even pass Id in?

```
  $id = $_POST['id'];
  $uredi = new urejanje();
  $uredi->uredi($id);
```

In any case I think You'll need to show us whats inside Funkcije.php

Comment: The function uredi() that I posted is inside Funkcije.php

Comment: which is why we need to see the rest of the file as the faulty code may be in the file

Comment: I tried moving the function to uredi.php and it's still returning the error, so I guess that's not it