# PHP form processing using JQuery not Working

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, validation

I'm processing a form using `PHP` and `JQuery` and it's not processing the way it should normally process. My `HTML` is:

```
    <form action="" method="POST" name="forgot_pass_form">
      <label><h3>Please Enter your email!</h3></label><br>
      <input type="text" name="email_pass" id="email_pass" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

My `JQuery` code which is in the same page as `HTML` code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function($) {

        var email = $('#email_pass').val();

        $("#submit").live('click', function(){
                $.post('email_password.php', 
                {
                'email_pass' : email
                }, 
                function(data) {
                    alert(data);                
                });

                return false;
            });
    }); 
</script>
```

My `PHP` code which is on `email_password.php`:

```
<?php


    $email = $_POST['email_pass'];

    if(empty($email)){
        echo  'empty';  
    } else {
        echo 'Not'; 
    }
?>
```

The problem here is it always alert me with `empty` even if I've entered something in the `text box`

I even tried this way:

```
 if(empty($_POST)){
    echo 'empty';    
   } else {
    // process the form 
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    if(empty($email)){
        echo 'Email is empty';
    } else {
        echo 'Email is not empty';  
    }
}
```

By trying this way, it alerts me with `Email is empty`. Please help

Comment: what your network console says , is it posting "post" params?

Comment: What jQuery version are you using?

Comment: I think it's `1.9` or `1.10`. The problem was that I was not using `var email` inside the `.live()` method. It's solved :)

Comment: @user3293145 Please check out my **[answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20150130/ajax-and-php-to-enter-multiple-forms-input-to-database/20150474#20150474)** for a thorough AJAX example

Comment: @MonkeyZeus What to use for `.attr('action')` if the form is submitting to itself using `form action=""`?

Comment: If you are following my example then **your** form should start like this `<form action="email_password.php" method="POST" id="my_form">`

Comment: No problem, I hope my example helps you going forward! Also, `$.post()` is just a wrapper-function which calls upon `$.ajax()` and defaults a lot of the parameters so technically speaking `$.post()` takes `.001%` more processing overhead lol. I personally find `$.post()` far too restrictive for my needs.

Comment: One last thing, check out **[this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21617685/2191572)** for a guide to debugging AJAX calls because you will inevitably need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function($) {



        $("#submit").live('click', function(){
 var email = $('#email_pass').val();
                $.post('email_password.php', 
                {
                'email_pass' : email
                }, 
                function(data) {
                    alert(data);                
                });

                return false;
            });
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: add the var email = $('#email_pass').val(); inside the  $("#submit").live('click', function(){

Comment: What difference does it make? @user3293145 although not the solution, `.live()` is deprecated, your should upgrade your jQuery and use `.on()`.

Comment: @ I Can Has Cheezburger.  i know but he is using old version

Comment: I'm using `CMS` and even after upgrading `JQuery`, `.on()` doesn't work most of the time while `.live()` does

Comment: Yeah, it's asking me to wait for 2 minutes @Ananth

Answer (score 3):

When you try to capture a field value, it must be the same name. The name you have in your form is '**email_pass**' and in your PHP code you are waiting for '**email**'

This should be:

```
if(empty($_POST)){
    echo 'empty';    
   } else {
    // process the form 
    $email = $_POST['email_pass']; // The field form name
    if(empty($email)){
        echo 'Email is empty';
    } else {
        echo 'Email is not empty';  
    }
}
```

Sorry for my english :s

Comment: Sorry that was a silly mistake, but I still get the same response as before, nothing changes

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that your making a `$_POST` call with jQuery and in that function you "post" under the new name `email_pass`. Update your PHP file to reference `$_POST['email_pass']` and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Use `0n()` and get email value inside the click function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function($) {

          $("#submit").on('click', function(){
                var email = $('#email_pass').val();
                $.post('email_password.php', 
                {
                'email_pass' : email
                }, 
                function(data) {
                    alert(data);                
                });

                return false;
            });
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Listening for the click of the button is improper. You must listen for form submission to properly catch the event in ALL browsers. `$('form[name="forgot_pass_form"]').on('submit', functione(){});`

Comment: Would it make difference on different browser if `.on('click')` is used instead of `.on('submit')`? @MonkeyZeus

Comment: @user3293145 that is exactly what I said, yes. Listening for the click of a button is a different event compared to the submission of a form. Even though `click` is working for you, it is not 100% reliable. Listening for a submit is 100% reliable.