# Sending form inputs to the server using jquery-ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have been having problems sending form data inputs to the server. I have tried alerting each form input and its giving me empty alerts here is my code: From my code its been alerting 0. When I post normally, it works.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

     //dataString = $('#form_user').serialize();
     var details = new FormData(document.getElementById('form_user'));
     $('#form_user').submit(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"<?= base_url('form/insertUser'); ?>",
            type:"POST",
            data: details,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(data){
                var result = $.parseJSON(data); 
                alert(result.id);
            },
            error: function(error,status,strErr){
                alert(strErr);
            }

        }); 
        return false;

    });

 });

</script>
```

My Html:

```
<div id="user" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4 id="myModalLabel">Add User</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>
            <div class ="error">

            </div>
            <form class="form-inline" name="form_user" id="form_user" >
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="input-prepend span4 form-span">
                        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
                        <input class="span4" type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Firstname">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-prepend span4 form-span">
                        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
                        <input class="span4" type="text" name="sname" placeholder="Surname">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="input-prepend span4 form-span">
                        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></span>
                        <input class="span4" type="text" placeholder="Email address" name="email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-prepend span4 form-span">
                        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th-list"></i></span>
                        <select name="gender" class="span4" data-placeholder="Gender" >
                            <option value="">Gender</option>
                            <option value="Male">Male</option>
                            <option value="Female">Female</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-prepend span4 form-span">
                        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th-list"></i></span>
                        <select name="group" class="span4" data-placeholder="Group" >
                            <option value="">Group</option>
                            <option value="1">Member</option>
                            <option value="2">Admin</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="row">  
                    <div class="input-prepend span4 form-span">
                        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th-list"></i></span>

                        <select class="chosen span4" name="country" >
                            <option value="" >Choose a Country...</option>
                            <option value="United States">United States</option>
                            <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
                            <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
                            <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
                            <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
                            <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
                            <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
                            <option value="Angola">Angola</option>
                            <option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
                            <option value="Antarctica">Antarctica</option>
                            <option value="Antigua and Barbuda">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
                            <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
                            <option value="Armenia">Armenia</option>
                            <option value="Aruba">Aruba</option>
                            <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
                            <option value="Austria">Austria</option>
                            <option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option>
                            <option value="Bahamas">Bahamas</option>
                            <option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>
                            <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
                            <option value="Barbados">Barbados</option>
                            <option value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
                            <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
                            <option value="Belize">Belize</option>
                            <option value="Benin">Benin</option>
                            <option value="Bermuda">Bermuda</option>
                            <option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option>
                            <option value="Bolivia">Bolivia</option>
                            <option value="Bosnia and Herzegovina">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
                            <option value="Botswana">Botswana</option>
                            <option value="Bouvet Island">Bouvet Island</option>
                            <option value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
                            <option value="British Indian Ocean Territory">British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
                            <option value="Brunei Darussalam">Brunei Darussalam</option>
                            <option value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option>
                            <option value="Burkina Faso">Burkina Faso</option>
                            <option value="Burundi">Burundi</option>
                            <option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option>
                            <option value="Cameroon">Cameroon</option>
                            <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
                            <option value="Cape Verde">Cape Verde</option>
                            <option value="Cayman Islands">Cayman Islands</option>
                            <option value="Central African Republic">Central African Republic</option>
                            <option value="Chad">Chad</option>
                            <option value="Chile">Chile</option>
                            <option value="China">China</option>
                            <option value="Christmas Island">Christmas Island</option>
                            <option value="Cocos (Keeling) Islands">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option>
                            <option value="Colombia">Colombia</option>
                            <option value="Comoros">Comoros</option>
                            <option value="Congo">Congo</option>
                            <option value="Congo, The Democratic Republic of The">Congo, The Democratic Republic of The</option>
                            <option value="Cook Islands">Cook Islands</option>
                            <option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option>
                            <option value="Cote D'ivoire">Cote D'ivoire</option>
                            <option value="Croatia">Croatia</option>
                            <option value="Cuba">Cuba</option>
                            <option value="Cyprus">Cyprus</option>
                            <option value="Czech Republic">Czech Republic</option>
                            <option value="Denmark">Denmark</option>
                            <option value="Djibouti">Djibouti</option>
                            <option value="Dominica">Dominica</option>
                            <option value="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic</option>
                            <option value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option>
                            <option value="Egypt">Egypt</option>
                            <option value="El Salvador">El Salvador</option>
                            <option value="Equatorial Guinea">Equatorial Guinea</option>
                            <option value="Eritrea">Eritrea</option>
                            <option value="Estonia">Estonia</option>
                            <option value="Ethiopia">Ethiopia</option>
                            <option value="Falkland Islands (Malvinas)">Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</option>
                            <option value="Faroe Islands">Faroe Islands</option>
                            <option value="Fiji">Fiji</option>
                            <option value="Finland">Finland</option>
                            <option value="France">France</option>
                            <option value="French Guiana">French Guiana</option>
                            <option value="French Polynesia">French Polynesia</option>
                            <option value="French Southern Territories">French Southern Territories</option>
                            <option value="Gabon">Gabon</option>
                            <option value="Gambia">Gambia</option>
                            <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
                            <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
                            <option value="Ghana">Ghana</option>
                            <option value="Gibraltar">Gibraltar</option>
                            <option value="Greece">Greece</option>
                            <option value="Greenland">Greenland</option>
                            <option value="Grenada">Grenada</option>
                            <option value="Guadeloupe">Guadeloupe</option>
                            <option value="Guam">Guam</option>
                            <option value="Guatemala">Guatemala</option>
                            <option value="Guinea">Guinea</option>
                            <option value="Guinea-bissau">Guinea-bissau</option>
                            <option value="Guyana">Guyana</option>
                            <option value="Haiti">Haiti</option>
                            <option value="Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands">Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands</option>
                            <option value="Holy See (Vatican City State)">Holy See (Vatican City State)</option>
                            <option value="Honduras">Honduras</option>
                            <option value="Hong Kong">Hong Kong</option>
                            <option value="Hungary">Hungary</option>
                            <option value="Iceland">Iceland</option>
                            <option value="India">India</option>
                            <option value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option>
                            <option value="Iran, Islamic Republic of">Iran, Islamic Republic of</option>
                            <option value="Iraq">Iraq</option>
                            <option value="Ireland">Ireland</option>
                            <option value="Israel">Israel</option>
                            <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
                            <option value="Jamaica">Jamaica</option>
                            <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
                            <option value="Jordan">Jordan</option>
                            <option value="Kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</option>
                            <option value="Kenya">Kenya</option>
                            <option value="Kiribati">Kiribati</option>
                            <option value="Korea, Democratic People's Republic of">Korea, Democratic People's Republic of</option>
                            <option value="Korea, Republic of">Korea, Republic of</option>
                            <option value="Kuwait">Kuwait</option>
                            <option value="Kyrgyzstan">Kyrgyzstan</option>
                            <option value="Lao People's Democratic Republic">Lao People's Democratic Republic</option>
                            <option value="Latvia">Latvia</option>
                            <option value="Lebanon">Lebanon</option>
                            <option value="Lesotho">Lesotho</option>
                            <option value="Liberia">Liberia</option>
                            <option value="Libyan Arab Jamahiriya">Libyan Arab Jamahiriya</option>
                            <option value="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</option>
                            <option value="Lithuania">Lithuania</option>
                            <option value="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</option>
                            <option value="Macao">Macao</option>
                            <option value="Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of">Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of</option>
                            <option value="Madagascar">Madagascar</option>
                            <option value="Malawi">Malawi</option>
                            <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
                            <option value="Maldives">Maldives</option>
                            <option value="Mali">Mali</option>
                            <option value="Malta">Malta</option>
                            <option value="Marshall Islands">Marshall Islands</option>
                            <option value="Martinique">Martinique</option>
                            <option value="Mauritania">Mauritania</option>
                            <option value="Mauritius">Mauritius</option>
                            <option value="Mayotte">Mayotte</option>
                            <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
                            <option value="Micronesia, Federated States of">Micronesia, Federated States of</option>
                            <option value="Moldova, Republic of">Moldova, Republic of</option>
                            <option value="Monaco">Monaco</option>
                            <option value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option>
                            <option value="Montenegro">Montenegro</option>
                            <option value="Montserrat">Montserrat</option>
                            <option value="Morocco">Morocco</option>
                            <option value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option>
                            <option value="Myanmar">Myanmar</option>
                            <option value="Namibia">Namibia</option>
                            <option value="Nauru">Nauru</option>
                            <option value="Nepal">Nepal</option>
                            <option value="Netherlands">Netherlands</option>
                            <option value="Netherlands Antilles">Netherlands Antilles</option>
                            <option value="New Caledonia">New Caledonia</option>
                            <option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>
                            <option value="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</option>
                            <option value="Niger">Niger</option>
                            <option value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option>
                            <option value="Niue">Niue</option>
                            <option value="Norfolk Island">Norfolk Island</option>
                            <option value="Northern Mariana Islands">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
                            <option value="Norway">Norway</option>
                            <option value="Oman">Oman</option>
                            <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
                            <option value="Palau">Palau</option>
                            <option value="Palestinian Territory, Occupied">Palestinian Territory, Occupied</option>
                            <option value="Panama">Panama</option>
                            <option value="Papua New Guinea">Papua New Guinea</option>
                            <option value="Paraguay">Paraguay</option>
                            <option value="Peru">Peru</option>
                            <option value="Philippines">Philippines</option>
                            <option value="Pitcairn">Pitcairn</option>
                            <option value="Poland">Poland</option>
                            <option value="Portugal">Portugal</option>
                            <option value="Puerto Rico">Puerto Rico</option>
                            <option value="Qatar">Qatar</option>
                            <option value="Reunion">Reunion</option>
                            <option value="Romania">Romania</option>
                            <option value="Russian Federation">Russian Federation</option>
                            <option value="Rwanda">Rwanda</option>
                            <option value="Saint Helena">Saint Helena</option>
                            <option value="Saint Kitts and Nevis">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
                            <option value="Saint Lucia">Saint Lucia</option>
                            <option value="Saint Pierre and Miquelon">Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option>
                            <option value="Saint Vincent and The Grenadines">Saint Vincent and The Grenadines</option>
                            <option value="Samoa">Samoa</option>
                            <option value="San Marino">San Marino</option>
                            <option value="Sao Tome and Principe">Sao Tome and Principe</option>
                            <option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option>
                            <option value="Senegal">Senegal</option>
                            <option value="Serbia">Serbia</option>
                            <option value="Seychelles">Seychelles</option>
                            <option value="Sierra Leone">Sierra Leone</option>
                            <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
                            <option value="Slovakia">Slovakia</option>
                            <option value="Slovenia">Slovenia</option>
                            <option value="Solomon Islands">Solomon Islands</option>
                            <option value="Somalia">Somalia</option>
                            <option value="South Africa">South Africa</option>
                            <option value="South Georgia and The South Sandwich Islands">South Georgia and The South Sandwich Islands</option>
                            <option value="South Sudan">South Sudan</option>
                            <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
                            <option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
                            <option value="Sudan">Sudan</option>
                            <option value="Suriname">Suriname</option>
                            <option value="Svalbard and Jan Mayen">Svalbard and Jan Mayen</option>
                            <option value="Swaziland">Swaziland</option>
                            <option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
                            <option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option>
                            <option value="Syrian Arab Republic">Syrian Arab Republic</option>
                            <option value="Taiwan, Republic of China">Taiwan, Republic of China</option>
                            <option value="Tajikistan">Tajikistan</option>
                            <option value="Tanzania, United Republic of">Tanzania, United Republic of</option>
                            <option value="Thailand">Thailand</option>
                            <option value="Timor-leste">Timor-leste</option>
                            <option value="Togo">Togo</option>
                            <option value="Tokelau">Tokelau</option>
                            <option value="Tonga">Tonga</option>
                            <option value="Trinidad and Tobago">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
                            <option value="Tunisia">Tunisia</option>
                            <option value="Turkey">Turkey</option>
                            <option value="Turkmenistan">Turkmenistan</option>
                            <option value="Turks and Caicos Islands">Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
                            <option value="Tuvalu">Tuvalu</option>
                            <option value="Uganda">Uganda</option>
                            <option value="Ukraine">Ukraine</option>
                            <option value="United Arab Emirates">United Arab Emirates</option>
                            <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
                            <option value="United States">United States</option>
                            <option value="United States Minor Outlying Islands">United States Minor Outlying Islands</option>
                            <option value="Uruguay">Uruguay</option>
                            <option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option>
                            <option value="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option>
                            <option value="Venezuela">Venezuela</option>
                            <option value="Viet Nam">Viet Nam</option>
                            <option value="Virgin Islands, British">Virgin Islands, British</option>
                            <option value="Virgin Islands, U.S.">Virgin Islands, U.S.</option>
                            <option value="Wallis and Futuna">Wallis and Futuna</option>
                            <option value="Western Sahara">Western Sahara</option>
                            <option value="Yemen">Yemen</option>
                            <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
                            <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
                        </select>

                    </div>
                    <div class="input-prepend span4 form-span">
                        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
                        <input class="span4" type="number" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" >
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-prepend span4 form-span">
                        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-key"></i></span>
                        <input class="span4" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-prepend span4 form-span">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>

        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <p></p>

    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public function insertUser(){
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname','Firstname','trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('sname','Surname','trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('gender','Gender','trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone','Phone','trim|required|numeric|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','trim|required|xss_clean|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','trim|required|xss_clean'); 
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('group','Group','trim|required|xss_clean');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
        $json = array('id'=>0,'msg'=>validation_errors('<p class="error">','</p>'));
        echo json_encode($json);

    }else{
        //insertion takes place here
        $this->load->model('admin_model');
        $fname = $this->input->post('fname');
        $sname = $this->input->post('sname');
        $gender = $this->input->post('gender');
        $phone = $this->input->post('phone');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $username = $this->input->post('email');
        $country = $this->input->post('country');
        $group = $this->input->post('group');
        $data = array(

            'email'=>$username,
            'password'=>$password,
            'active'=>1,
            'fname'=>$fname,
            'lname'=>$sname,
            'phone'=>$phone,
            'phone'=>$phone,
            'country'=>$country,
            'gender'=>$gender,
            'group'=>$group

            );

        $table = 'users';
        $this->admin_model->insert($table,$data);
        $json = array('id'=>1,'msg'=>'User Successfully Created!!!');
        echo json_encode($json);
    }
}
```

Comment: Start simple: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20150130/ajax-and-php-to-enter-multiple-forms-input-to-database/20150474#20150474** and please narrow down the code you have posted. There are approximately ZERO people who want to muddle through that much HTML. When you are ready to debug AJAX like the pros then check this out: **http://stackoverflow.com/a/21617685/2191572**

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using jQuery, you can use .serialize() jQuery method.

```
var details = $('#form_user').serialize();
```

This will solve your problem.

You can use

```
contentType: 'json'
```

And then you will not need to use 'parseJSON'. Your data will be received already as a Javascript Object.