# Calling a PHP function with parameters form URL via Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

Please have a look at the following code

....The Javascript code in ctp file...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){


   $( ".btn-danger" ).click(function(){
        console.log("Red Button");
        var toclose = $(this).parent().parent();
        $.ajax({
          url: "../img/media.jpg",
        }).done(function() {
            console.log( "The act has been done");
            toclose.toggle();
          });
   }); 


   $( ".btn-success" ).click(function(){
      console.log("Red Button");
      idOfButton = $(this).attr('id');
      var toclose = $(this).parent().parent();
      $.ajax({
        url: "../img/media.jpg",
      }).done(function() {
          increment(idOfButton);
            alert(idOfButton);
      console.log( "The act has been done");
          toclose.toggle();
      });
 }); 

  $( ".xy" ).click(function(){

    $(this).find("#enside1").toggle();
    $(this).find("#ptside1").toggle();
    console.log(this);
  });

      function xxx(id)
  {
      alert(id);
  }

  function increment(uniqueWord)
  {
      $.ajax({
          url: "http://localhost/cake2/flip2/correct",
                  data: {word: uniqueWord}

        }).done(function() {
            console.log( "The act has been done");
            toclose.toggle();
          });

    }

});


</script>
```

Please consider this function

```
function increment(uniqueWord)
  {
      $.ajax({
          url: "http://localhost/cake2/flip2/correct",
                  data: {word: uniqueWord}

        }).done(function() {
            console.log( "The act has been done");
            toclose.toggle();
          });

    }
```

Here I am trying to call a method in a PHP file. That method contains a parameter.

```
public function correct($word)
        {
            $this->Flip2->correctAnswer(89,$word);

        }
```

However there is an issue in passing the parameter values to the PHP method. It simply do not work. If I remove the parameters from "all" the places and just call the `url: "http://localhost/cake2/flip2/correct",` this works fine. What I have done wrong when passing the values to the PHP method via the Ajax call?

Comment: How do you call `correct` function?

Comment: Quick fix: `$this->Flip2->correctAnswer(89,$_GET['word']);`. You can learn how to properly debug AJAX calls **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21617685/2191572)**

Comment: For a more full-featured AJAX usage explanation you can review **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20150130/ajax-and-php-to-enter-multiple-forms-input-to-database/20150474#20150474)**

Comment: @AmalMurali: This is how ` url: http://localhost/cake2/flip2/correct`

Comment: @RahilWazir: CakePHP. MVP Pattern.

Comment: @HashMap I said what is `flip2`? Is this your controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass the word in the URL:

```
function increment(uniqueWord)
  {
  $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost/cake2/flip2/correct/" + uniqueWord,
      //...
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I did too.

Answer (score 0):

As Another solution you can change ajax call to be post request and get data in your controller from $this->request->data

```
 $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost/cake2/flip2/correct",
      data: {word: uniqueWord},
      type: 'post'
    }).done(function() {
        console.log( "The act has been done");
        toclose.toggle();
      });
```

Controller will be

```
public function correct()
    {
        $this->Flip2->correctAnswer(89,$this->request->data['word']);

    }
```