# How to make AJAX calls - Elgg

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, elgg

I'm trying to make an AJAX call in [elgg](https://elgg.org/), but I've been unsuccessful so far. What could I be doing wrong, or what am I missing?

Thank you all in advance.

**Elgg version 2.1.1**

**start.php**

```
// in myplugin_init()
elgg_register_ajax_view('forms/myplugin/add');
```

**default/forms/myplugin/add.php**

```
<div>Successful AJAX call</div>
```

**default/object/my_ajax_plugin.php**

```
<div class="myplugin-form-container">JQ Here</div>

<script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">

    var Ajax = require('elgg/Ajax');
    var ajax = new Ajax();

    ajax.form('myplugin/add').done(function (output, statusText, jqXHR) {
        if (jqXHR.AjaxData.status == -1) {
            return;
        }
            $('.myplugin-form-container').html(output);
    });

</script>
```

Comment: [Is there any reason for avoiding jQuery's AJAX calling mechanism?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20150130/ajax-and-php-to-enter-multiple-forms-input-to-database/20150474#20150474). I've never used Elgg but it looks like it merely provides a wrapper for `$.ajax()`

Comment: [Elgg](https://elgg.org/) is a CMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elgg uses [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html) for dependencies loading. You can't just throw require inline and expect it to work. You could try:

```
require(['elgg/Ajax'], Ajax => {
  var ajax = new Ajax();
  ajax.view('developers/ajax_demo.html').then(body => {
    console.log('RESULT', body)
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This might seem really obvious, but how can I go about attaching an `onClick`, say on a `DIV` getting clicked. This is part of what I'm struggling with.

Comment: Would you please mind illustrating. I would very much appreciate it.