# why $.ajax does not work with me?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i don't know why $.ajax never called on my code ?
i use xampp as localhost 
jquery called ok , so when i click on the button , the text below it changed .. but $.ajax part never execute ?

my page :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="layout/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="layout/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="layout/css/mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="alert alert-danger"> alerts alerts </div>
<div class="alert alert-danger"> alerts alerts </div>
<div class="alert alert-danger"> alerts alerts </div>
<button id="btn" class="btn btn-primary">cliquer ici </button>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="layout/js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="layout/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="layout/js/myjs.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

my js :

```
$(document).on('click','#btn',function(){
    var ID =$(this).attr('id');
    $(this).html("loading ... ");
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"http://localhost/my_projects/testing/moremore.php",
        data:"id="+ID,
        success: function(html){
            $('.container').append(html);
            $('#btn').html("done");
        }
    });
    $(this).html("hmmmm ... ");
});
```

and my moremore.php :

```
<div class="alert alert-success"> alerts alerts by ajax </div>
```

Comment: You should check your browser console for errors

Comment: No error messages shown on my chrome console :/

Comment: Check out [**AJAX Tutorial**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20150130/ajax-and-php-to-enter-multiple-forms-input-to-database/20150474#20150474) and [**Network Tab Tutorial**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21617685/2191572)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code, and it pretty much works as is. The only thing that I changed was the ajax url from absolute `http://localhost/my_projects/testing/moremore.php` to relative `moremore.php` and I threw in the [official jQuery CDN](http://code.jquery.com/) in case yours was borked.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>test</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-JmvOoLtYsmqlsWxa7mDSLMwa6dZ9rrIdtrrVYRnDRH0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="layout/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="layout/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="layout/css/mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="alert alert-danger"> alerts alerts </div>
<div class="alert alert-danger"> alerts alerts </div>
<div class="alert alert-danger"> alerts alerts </div>
<button id="btn" class="btn btn-primary">cliquer ici </button>
</div>
<script>
$(document).on('click','#btn',function(){
    var ID =$(this).attr('id');
    $(this).html("loading ... ");
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"moremore.php",
        data:"id="+ID,
        success: function(html){
            $('.container').append(html);
            $('#btn').html("done");
        }
    });
    $(this).html("hmmmm ... ");
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="layout/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="layout/js/myjs.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`moremore.php`:

```
<div class="alert alert-success"> alerts alerts by ajax </div>
```

Results in this expected output after a couple clicks:

[image: screenshot of it working]

Comment: @OuailBellal glad it works for you :) feel free to accept if it answers the question for you. this will result in +2 rep for you. see: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/321521)

Answer (score 1):

1) Look for console.log errors or errors in network header

2) Make sure you .php script where you are requesting the ajax, has major headers to allow access control.

3) Sometimes, the headers doesn't allow to make you request.

4) When making request, keep your console opened (F12) and enable Log XMLhttpRequest

Try adding these headers to you moremore.php

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost");
```

Also to give it a try, check the ajax request with the ajax header, add this too in your moremore.php:

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
     echo '<div class="alert alert-success"> alerts alerts by ajax </div>';
} else {
    echo 'no ajax';
}
```

This will give you an idea if ajax request is working fine or not.

New ajax js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn').click(function() {
    var ID = $(this).attr('id');
    $(this).html("Loading ... ");
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost/my_projects/testing/moremore.php",
      data: {
        id: ID
      },
      cache: false,
      xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
      },
      dataType: html,
      success: function(html) {
        $('.container').append(html);
        $('#btn').html("done");
      },
      error: function() {
        alert("Something went wrong");
        $("#btn").html("hmmmm, it was called... ");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Do leave comments for more help!

Comment: thnks for your comment 
but the same , i can't see any errors in my console .. 
ps : when i use (ready function ) it does not work at all :) but when i delete it , part of my code work but not $.ajax

Comment: Can you pastebin your whole code? You say if you add $document ready, it doesn't work at all, that is not a point of concern, try up the new thing we shared and see it.

Comment: js : http://pastebin.com/Y8a4ReJa
html : http://pastebin.com/mtHbfQzx
php : http://pastebin.com/cvhe62WD

Comment: Try Moving the scripts into the <head> sections.
You must of getting atleast one part from the code, either the div or no ajax. What do you get?

Comment: O.o when i move script part to the head , , it does not work at all 
and i got nothing , even if i put script in the last of my code (after /div )

Comment: So you say, the ajax request is not being made? You are not getting anything at all? Open Chrome, enable log xmlhtttprequest and then check if ajax is being sent of not.

Comment: Can u share your teamviewer id or email, i may try to assist you and look into what's exactly the matter is.

Answer (score -1):

Try to wrap anonymous function, and change selector document to '#btn'

```
(function($) {
$('#btn').on('click',function(){
    var ID =$(this).attr('id');
    $(this).html("loading ... ");
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"http://localhost/my_projects/testing/moremore.php",
    data:"id="+ID,
    success: function(html){
        $('.container').append(html);
        $('#btn').html("done");
    }
});
$(this).html("hmmmm ... ");
   });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Nothing in OP suggests something would overwrite `$` reference

Comment: try this code    `$('#btn').on('click', function() { alert('clicked'); });`

Comment: btw , this part work good 
        $(this).html("loading ... ");
+
        $(this).html("hmmmm ... ");
but $.ajax part i don't why not working

Comment: The fact that OP said *"when i click on the button , the text below it changed"* is a good clue that this is not the answer.